# more exact position css

Tags: css, position

I have a **position:** element in css, is there a more exact version that uses px like, for example,

```
 position: 100px left;
```

is there any similar way to do that in css?

Comment: Do you mean `left: 100px;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Position property

The position property specifies the type of positioning method used for an element (static, relative, fixed or absolute).

The position property specifies the type of positioning method used for an element.

There are four different position values:

- static
- relative
- fixed
- absolute

## Position shorthand

No `short-hand` exists to combine all of position-dependent property values. These are all different properties, unlike, for instance `background`, which has `color`, `image`, `position` and `repeat` instructions and as such can be coalesced into a short-hand form:

**Normal form**

```
#element{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("bg_img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**Shorthand form**

```
#element{
    background: #ffffff url("bg_img.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

## Answering your question

If you are after a method to position an element such that it has **100px** space at the left, you may do that like these (which depends on your structure and with the provided information it is hard to say how, so you may provide more information for an exact situation):

```
#element{ margin-left: 100px; }
```

or

```
#element{ padding-left: 100px; }
```

or

```
#element{ position: absolute; left: 100px; }
```

or

```
#element{ position: relative; left: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The position you want is `absolute`, I think:

However, your syntax isn't quite correct.

---

## Positioning an Element.

Position: **PositionProperty**;

There are a few position properties:

- Absolute
- Static (default)
- Fixed
- Relative

These are the most used properties;

Now, if you want an element that has an absolute position, choose `position:absolute;`

In your case, the CSS you're probably looking for willbe:

```
#ElementID {
  position:absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

## A working example

---

```css
#absoluteDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left:100px;
  }

.colorblock {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #00F;
  }
```

```html
<div id="absoluteDiv" class="colorblock">
</div>
```

Run the snippet above for a working example.

Hope it helped :)

**EDIT** For more information about positioning elements, click [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
.selector {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
```